# How do I trigger an element-based HTMX GET request from vanilla JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, htmx

Using [HTMX](https://htmx.org/), I have an element rigged up with `hx-get` and `hx-trigger`, and it works fine. But under certain circumstances, I want the GET request to trigger from some vanilla JavaScript logic (which is not based on user input).

I've looked through the JavaScript API, and I'm just not seeing it. There's an `htmx.trigger()`, but it seems to just trigger the standard HTML events, not an element-based event.

I can do this all manually in JavaScript, of course, but I feel like there *has* to be a way to get HTMX to do it.

Comment: what "non-element-based" event trigger are you using within the element? you can send any event, including custom events, with `htmx.trigger()`... can you please post a bit of code?

Comment: I figured it out. Posted my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

I got it.

You can do this in the `hx-trigger` element:

```
<input hx-trigger="[all your other triggers], doSearch from:body" ...
```

The trigger will now work in the all the other ways defined, and it will also listen for an event called `doSearch` from the BODY element..

You raise that event like this:

```
// Do a bunch of logic here, then...
document.body.dispatchEvent(new Event('doSearch'));
```